# Connect internal SSD as external via USB

Tags: boot, usb, ssd, external-hdd

So I bought a new laptop which has an M.2 SSD. My old dead laptop has a 2.5" SSD. I want to access the data on the old drive. I bought an enclosure for the SSD which connects to a laptop via USB.Upon connecting nothing happens.Then I checked the amazon page which says "compatible with windows and macOS".
The question: Is there a hack around this and maybe even a way to boot from this drive?

Comment: Was your old laptop dead because the SSD had died?

Comment: @CharlesGreen It's also possible that the SSD is OK, and either the USB cable or the SSD was not connected securely.

Comment: @karel Indeed - but it's worth asking!

Answer (score 1):

Most external drive enclosures are compatible with Linux. Just because Amazon says "compatible with windows and macOS" doesn't mean that the 2.5" external drive enclosure isn't compatible with Linux too. Are you sure that you plugged the SSD firmly and securely into the 2.5" external drive enclosure, and that the USB cable isn't damaged and is connected securely? If the aforementioned doesn't work try inserting the USB cable into a different USB port.